# Find in collection/object - SailsJS and Waterline ORM

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

I'm using SailsJS, so Waterline ORM and MongoDB.

I'm saving multiple user IDs in an object within a collection called Labels (this is so that a label can belong to multiple users).

I have a data structure in Mongo something like this:

```
labels: {
    id: ...
    belongs_to: {
        **id of user**: 2 (I'm using this is for individual user ordering)
    }
}
```

If I'm currently user of id **101** - I want to find() all Label entries where 101 exists in labels.belongs_to.

I've searched the docs but can't find how to do this.

I've tried (with no luck) something similar to:

```
Label.find().where({ belongs_to: {'contains' : user_id})
```

Is this the best way to tackle this, and if so, how can I achieve this via Sails?

Answer (score 3):

Currently Waterline does not support querying embedded records, mostly because this is not simple to do across multiple DBs.

You can however use `Label.native(function(err, rawMongoCollection){/*...*/});` to get a raw Mongo collection and with it you should be able to do a similar query: [.native() docs](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/waterline/models/native.html).

Comment: Thanks Dário - any tips on the actual query? I can't seem to pass variables into the where. Eg. collection.find({ "label_belongs_to[**user_id**]" : {$gt: -1} }) - where user_id is the logged in user id.
This results in a syntax error because of the []

Comment: Is `collection` in your example a raw mongo collection? I'm no mongo expert but I believe it expects dot '.' notation, so something like `collection.find({ "label_belongs_to.user_id" : {$gt: -1} })`.