# What is the Waterline translation of 'collection' type with mongodb adapter?

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, waterline

I have a model (A) in waterline with the 'collection' type (which contains IDs of other model (B) instances). I would then like to find all records of A whose collection contains a specific ID of B.

First I tried 
`A.find({where: {collection_of_B: {contains: B_ID}}})`
which didn't return what I wanted. Then I found a [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30751253/find-in-collection-object-sailsjs-and-waterline-orm) saying that this type of query was not currently possible with waterline and that a native query to mongodb should be used instead. This brings me to my question as I first thought that a collection would be translated to an array in mongo but that doesn't seem to be the case.

I tried this query (based on [mongodb documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#match-an-array-element))

```
A.native(function(err, collection) {
  var cursor = collection.find({collection_of_B: B_ID});
  ....
```

But that didn't return anything either and when I instead tested to find documents based on a field that was just a string in my waterline model it worked as expected but I also couldn't see the collection type on the mongo document when I printed it to terminal.

So, how is a waterline collection attribute type stored in mongodb? And how do I make a query to find records with a specific value in the collection?

Comment: I looked in the database directly and apparantly waterline creates a separate "table" (mongo collection) for the collection type. But I dont have access to it as a waterline model so the second part of the question still stands.